# Lebesgue measure of non-measurable set times the null set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The title might not be accurate, but here is my question:

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on some measurable space $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{A})$. Assume $A\in \mathcal{A}$ is such that $A = X \times Y$, where $X$ is a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on some $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, and $Y = \emptyset$ or $Y = \{y\}$,  ${y}\in \mathbb{R}$. Is the Lebesgue measure of A identically equal to zero, or is it non-measurable? I know that generally $\lambda (A) \neq \lambda(X) \, \lambda(Y)$, still I would like to say that $\lambda(A) = 0$, since $A$ either has no extension in the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ or consists of line segments, which are null sets.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean $Y = \{y\}$ instead of $Y = y$. Also, the Lebesgue measure is usually not defined/considered on the whole power set, since it is not $\sigma$-additive there.

Finally, your set $A$ is always Lebesgue measurable with measure zero, since

$$
A \subset \mathbb{R} \times \{y\},
$$

where the right hand side is a null-set. But (since the Lebesgue measure is complete) subsets of null-sets are null-sets, so that $A$ is measurable with Lebesgue measure zero.

EDIT: Now that you have edited the question, it is important to point out that the argument above only works as long as we are talking about **Lebesgue measurability**. If we want to have **Borel measurability**, the claim is no longer true.

To see this, recall from the Fubini theorem that if $A$ is Borel measurable, then so is **every** "section"

$$A_z = \{x \in \Bbb{R} \mid (x,z) \in A\}.$$

If you apply this to $z = y$ with $Y=\{y\}$, we get $A_y = X$, which is not measurable. This shows that the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^2$, restricted to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is **not** complete.

Comment: I assume the OP meant the Lebesgue outer measure on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, my bad to define it on the whole power set. But the question is relevant for the Lebesgue outer measure as well, as Jason pointed out. I will edit the question with your comments in regard.

Thank you for your answer, now I know how to approach it.