# let N be Vitali set and $A=\{(x,a_0)∈\mathbb{R^2}|x∈N \} $($a_0$ is a fixed real number).Now which of following options is true?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

let  $\mathcal{N} $ be [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set) and $A=\{(x,a_0) \in \mathbb{R^2} \mid x \in \mathcal{N} \} $ ($a_0 $ is a fixed real number).Now which of following options is true ?

1.$A$ is  measurable set in $\mathbb{R^2}$

2.$A$ is a closed set in $\mathbb{R^2}$ for the  Euclidean distance.

3.$A$ is  measurable set but not closed.

4.$A$ is  measurable set with $\infty$ measure.

We know $A$ is not closed because we know $G \times H$ is closed iff $G$ is closed and $H$ is closed.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143277/lebesgue-measure-of-non-measurable-set-times-the-null-set?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

What is the Lebesgue measure of $B= \mathbb{R} \times\{ a_0\}$ ? And think of what it means for a measure to be complete.

Comment: So $A \subset B $ and $m(B) =0 \times \infty =0 $ so $m(A) =0 $ then "1" is true.

Comment: @amirbahadory not only 1, pick another too